# Odd behaviour of an NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have a Core Data project with an NSTableView bound to an NSArrayController. I have two buttons, one adding an object to the table and one removing the object from the table. The Add method uses a custom method which directly creates a new Core Data object. The remove method uses the standard Remove method of an NSArrayController.

My problem is that the selected object of the table doesn't seem to correspond to the selected object of the NSArrayController. If I log the selected object it seems to be different and the Remove method removes the objects in the order that they were created rather than removing the selected object.

For reference the table and some of the bindings are as follows:

**The table**

[http://emberapp.com/splash6/images/risk-engine-input-cells-table/sizes/m.png](http://emberapp.com/splash6/images/risk-engine-input-cells-table)

**The NSArrayController bindings**

[http://emberapp.com/splash6/images/nsarraycontroller-bindings/sizes/m.png](http://emberapp.com/splash6/images/nsarraycontroller-bindings)

**The bindings for a cell in the table**

[http://emberapp.com/splash6/images/cell-bindings/sizes/m.png](http://emberapp.com/splash6/images/cell-bindings)

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening. It seems to be one of those problems that has a really simple answer but I can't find it.

As suggested I have tried binding the selection indices, something I normally don't do, but this seems to have made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

did you remember to bind the selection indexes?

Comment: I normally don't do this, but have tried doing it in this case and it seems to have made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the columns bound to the same array controller?